# Javascript React - not navigating to redirect page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on an inventory management system built in ReactJS with a back-end MariaDB database.  The architecture includes user registration and logon modules with JWT authentication, a simple dashboard using D3, an inventory display screen using the React-Data-Table-Component, and an add inventory module. I will use the add-inventory module in the edit-inventory functionality by passing in a parameter to differentiate between add or edit mode (I have not yet implemented that parameter).  A user can click on a row on the inventory display screen to pull that record up in edit mode, but currently I am not getting to the page to allow for inventory edit.

My code (inventorylist.component.jsx) looks like this:

```
    updateRecord = row => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        selectedRow: row,
        editSelectedRow: true
    }, () => {
        console.log('UPDATED STATE:',this.state.selectedRow)
    })
}

    editRecord = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    return <Link to='/add' />
    //return <Redirect to='/add' />
    // return (
    //     <>
    //     <Router>
    //         <Switch>
    //             <Route path='/add' component={AddInventory} />
    //         </Switch>
    //     </Router>
    //     </>
    // )

}

    render() {
    const inventoryTitle = this.props.jwt.username + "'s Inventory"
    return (
        <>
        <DataTable 
            title={inventoryTitle}
            striped={true}
            highlightOnHover={true}
            fixedHeader={true}
            pagination={true}
            paginationPerPage={10}
            onRowClicked={this.updateRecord}
            columns={columns} 
            data={this.state.inventory} 
        />
        <button type='button' onClick={this.editRecord}>Edit</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

This is not navigating to the add-inventory component.  I have put a console.log into the editRecord function to verify that it is getting into that function after clicking on the button, but that's as far as it seems to be going.

I'm sure I'm just missing something fairly obvious here, but does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history` object to navigate imperatively:

```
history.push(<path>);
```

[Read more](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history) about `history`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are return a `Link` which is a JSX element. What you need to do is one of the following:

1. If you want to keep the `button` element, you can push a new route into the history like this: `history.push('/edit')`
2. If you want to use `Link`, you need to replace you `button` with it and, when you click the link, it will automatically navigate there

**With Hooks**

If you were using hooks, you could use the `useHistory` hook provided by `react-router` to navigate to a different route doing something like this:

```
const history = useHistory();

const editRecord = () => {
    history.push('/app');
};
```